# Change the status using the position in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am writing a class file that includes a listview that shows the status of each particular person.

- When I click the list it goes to another page Showing corresponding
  the userDetails.
- When i click the change status, it goes to another    page where u
  can change the current status.

Now whatever change i made in this page should reflect on my first page on the corresponding showing list user. I am using fragments.Could somebody please help me?

```
 private class ListViewSummaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context con;
    SummaryModel sumModel;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    CircularImageView image;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    TextView accidentType, status;
    LinearLayout root;


    public ListViewSummaryAdapter(Context context, SummaryModel summaryModel) {

        con = context;
        sumModel = summaryModel;
        if (con != null) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sumModel.getDetails().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summarylistinner, parent, false);

        image = (CircularImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cV_summary_profileImage);
        accidentType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tV_summary_accident);
        status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tV_summary_status);
        root = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lL_summary_root);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();


        if (sumModel.getDetails().size() != 0) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +     homModel.getpost().get(position).getAttachments().get(position).getImages().getThumbnail().getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            imageLoader.displayImage((sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getUser_details().getUser_profilePic()), image, options,
                    new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

                        Animation rotation;

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                            rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                                    R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
                            rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                            //   image.startAnimation(rotation);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                                                      Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            image.clearAnimation();
                            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        }
                    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view,
                                                     int current, int total) {
                        }
                    });
        }


        root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("UserName", sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getUser_details().getUser_firstName() + " " + sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getUser_details().getUser_lastName());
                bundle.putString("UserLocation", sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getUser_details().getUser_location());
                bundle.putString("UserReport", sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getReport_at());
                bundle.putString("UserLatitude", sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getUser_details().getUser_latitude());
                bundle.putString("UserLongitude", sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getUser_details().getUser_longitude());
                bundle.putString("UserStatus", sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getStatus());


                addFragment(new InnerSummaryFragment(), true, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE, "SummaryInner", bundle);
            }
        });

        if (sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getStatus().equals("0")) {
            if(SaveSharedPreference.getClosestatus(getActivity()).equals("YES"))
            {
                status.setText("Status : Closed");
            }
            else
            status.setText("Status : Open");
        }
        else if (sumModel.getDetails().get(position).getStatus().equals("2")) {
            status.setText("Status : Close");
        }


        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Please post you adapter code.

Comment: paste your code. you just need to pass the data with bundle.set to setArguments. startactivityforResult.(dont use getActivity if your list is on fragment).On onactivityresult just update the arraylist data and call notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: The section [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) contains useful tips you should keep in mind when asking a question.

Comment: Paste code of your addFragment() . there you need to change.and just update whether listadapter is coming from activity or fragment.?